# Insert ObservableList into a TableView JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, tablecolumn

I want to display all Prisoners data into a single TableView.
A prisoner looks like that (all the code is a sample) :

```
public class Prisoner {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private PrisonerCase case;
    Prisoner() {
        id = "Unknown";
        name = "Unknown";
        case = new PrisonerCase();
    }
}

public class PrisonerCase {
    private String id_case;
    private String date_case;
    PrisonerCase() {
        id_case = "unknown";
        date_case = "unknown";
    }
}
```

Then I have my TableView : 
data is an `ObservableList<Prisoner>` and return all the prisoners I have in my database. I build all prisoners and all the prisoner cases in the function  `getData()`.

```
TableView tv = new TableView();
data = Database.getData();
TableColumn id_column = new TableColumn("ID");
id_column.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Prisoner, String>("id"));
```

This works fine, but my question is, how can I add the case in the TableView ?
I tried

```
TableColumn n_case_column = new TableColumn("N° Case");
n_case_colmun.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<PrisonerCase, String>("id_case"));
```

But it doesn't work.
Of course, I didn't forget to add all the columns to the TableView at the end.

```
tv.setItems(data);
tv.getColmuns().addAll(id_column, n_case_column);
```

Comment: I think you should add columns to table view before items so your code should be `tv.getColmuns().addAll(id_column, n_case_column); tv.setItems(data);
` Also you should specify columns type such as  `TableColumn<Prisoner,String> columnName`

Comment: The fact to add columns before items didn't solve anything. But thank you for the columns types

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, **never** use raw types. The type of the `TableView` is the type of the objects representing each row (`Prisoner` in this case). The types of the `TableColumn`s are, first, the type of the `TableView`, and second, the type of the data displayed in each cell in that column.

So you should have

```
TableView<Prisoner> tv = new TableView<>();
TableColumn<Prisoner, String> idColumn = new TableColumn<>("ID");
TableColumn<Prisoner, String> nCaseColumn = new TableColumn<>("N° Case");
```

You didn't show the methods in your classes; I am going to assume you follow standard [Java naming conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java) (I changed some of your variable names above to conform to these too). Then you can do

```
idColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> 
    new SimpleStringProperty(cellData.getValue().getId()));
// or 
// idColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("id")); 
// but the first version above is better, imho

nCaseColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> 
    new SimpleStringProperty(cellData.getValue().getCase().getIdCase()));
```